# What is the difference between OpenVPN via terminal and via network manager?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

When setting up an OpenVPN connection via network manager I need to import a CA.crt file. This is the minimum requirement.

When using the terminal command `sudo openvpn config.conf` I just need the config file but no extra certificate.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely `config.conf` has the certificate inside it? OpenVPN config files I have used in the past all contain the relevant certificate.

Comment: Of course. I didn't think about it because I imported the config.ovpn into the network manager to create the connection. So I supposed that everything that was in that file was already used by network manager. Obviously, it omitts the CA-part and instead asks for it seperately.